# webpage to pdf conversion github page

Tags: python, html, github

I'm trying to convert my github page into pdf. But when I tried to conovert it, the converted pdf contains the message **"You are being redirected to your identity provider in order to authenticate"** . I'm using **pyppeteer** package for conversion. Can anyone help me with how to authenticate the code to convert my github page into pdf

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.